# Graph implementation adjacency list 1.0

Tags: c++, c++11, graph

Please note the following:

1. All edges are directed
2. Removal of edges/nodges is not implemented yet
3. A user of the class `Graph` can never (hopefully) access a `Node` directly
4. If one tries to add an edge to a node that does not exist, `insert_edge()` will do nothing.
5. A `Vertex` cannot point to another vertex with several edges.
6. While the base class `Graph` works perfectly, I would like to create more advance graphs that could be used for maximum flow algorithm, weighted graphed etc. by creating new classes and inherit functions from `Graph`. But this seems impossible by the current implementation. It seems that the only way for a smooth solution for this right now is to add more data members to `Node` (`int weight` for example). Any idea on what I can do for making this possible with inheriting from `Graph` instead?

```
class Node
{
public:


std::string get_name()const;

//protected:
Node() = default;

Node( const std::string & n )
: name(n)
{}

std::vector<Node*> neighbours;
private:
std::string name;
};
```

```
class Graph : public Node 
{
public:
void insert_node( std::string);
void insert_edge( std::string, std::string); 
void print_node( const std::string) const;
void print_graph() const;

protected:
void insert_edge( Node*, Node*);
Node* get_node( std::string ) const;
bool is_node( Node * );   

private:
std::vector<Node*> list;
};
```

```
std::string
Node::get_name() const
{
return name;
}
```

```
void
Graph::insert_node( std::string name)
{
for( auto& node  : list  )
{
  if( name == node -> get_name() )
  {
     return;
  }
}

Node *temp = new Node(name);
list.push_back ( temp );
}
```

```
void 
Graph::insert_edge( Node *n, Node *new_edge ) 
{
if( n == nullptr || new_edge == nullptr )
{
  return;
}

if( !is_node( n ) )
{
  return;
}

for( auto& node : list )
{
  if( n -> get_name() == node -> get_name() )
  {
     for( auto& current_edges : node -> neighbours )
     {
        if( current_edges -> get_name() == new_edge -> get_name() )
        {
           return;
        }
     } 
     node -> neighbours.push_back( new_edge );
  }
}
}
```

```
void
Graph::insert_edge( std::string n, std::string new_edge)
{
Node* temp1 = get_node( n );
Node* temp2 = get_node( new_edge );
insert_edge( temp1, temp2 );
}
```

```
Node*
Graph::get_node( std::string name ) const
{
   for( auto& node : list )
{
  if( name == node -> get_name() )
  {
     return node;
  }
}
return nullptr;
}
```

```
void
Graph::print_node( std::string name ) const
{  
std::cout << name << " : ";
for( auto&  node : list )
{
if(name == node -> get_name() )
  {
     for( auto& edge : node -> neighbours )
     {
        std::cout << " -> " << edge -> get_name();
     }
     std::cout << std::endl;
     break;
  }
}
}
```

```
void
Graph::print_graph() const
{
for( auto&  node : list )
{
  std::cout << node -> get_name() << " : ";
  for( auto& edge : node -> neighbours )
  {
   std::cout << " -> " << edge -> get_name();
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
}
```

```
bool
Graph::is_node( Node *n )
{
for( auto& node : list )
{
  if( node -> get_name() == n -> get_name() )
  {
     return true;
  }
}
return false; 
}
```

Comment: Did you omit a level of indentation pretty much everywhere intentionally, or was that a problem when pasting the code here?

Comment: My code is indentended in my editor, but my I pasted it here, the site complaided that it was not four whitespace so I just hitted the spacebar so it was 4 whitespace in the code...Is there a better way?

Comment: Humm, not that I know of... Which editor are you using? On Vim and Emacs is pretty easy to replace tabs with spaces...

Answer (score 2):

I don't like that `std::vector<Node*> neighbours;` is a data member with public scope in `Node`. I would suggest doing it `private` and provide a getter for it, or provide a `Node::push_back()`, etc.

As for you question of adding a data member weight in `Graph`, I think that's not very nice, since - in my mind - weight is an attribute every node has, thus it should be a data member of `Node`.

Comment: Neighbors should be protected so Graph can use it, but I have some compiling problems with that right now!




I guess I am not clear enough with my description!
I would like to great graphs with weights so I can implement dijkstra algorithm.




I would also like to great graphs with capacity so I can implement different maximum flow algorithms as well. This makes it problematic to store both weights, capacity, etc. in node.

Comment: Therefore, I think it is better to create a class Graph_Weight that inherit from class Graph and give that Graph weight instead of the class Node and another class Graph_capacity that have capacity.
I am clear with my thoughts?

Comment: @user1991779 I thought it was public, because you have commented protected! Maybe you could make an Edge class as well. However yes, your idea is nice too! :) Should I edit my answer or something or it is good as is? (because I saw that you didn't accept it).

Comment: I have made a lot of modifications, I will probably post it tomorrow. I would like to get some more comments on my choice of data structures!

Comment: Don't you think that the new ones should be a new question? Just an idea. I am not sure. :) @user1991779